# implicit declaration of function

Tags: c

When I compile my code written in C language I am getting following Warning and able to compile successfully

> warning:implicit declaration of function

What will happen if I ignore this warning?

Comment: Compile - which language? C?

Comment: I suggest following a C beginners tutorial. 1st or 2nd chapter

Comment: By compile you mean both compile and link or just compile ? If the function is not defined anywhere, then you will get a linker error.

Comment: By compile I mean both compile and link. And the function is defined and I get this warning.

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen if I ignore this warning?

That depends on the situation. If the implicitly declared function is not defined in any of the libraries you link against, you'll simply get a link error.

If it is defined and its definition matches the implicit declaration (i.e. the return type is `int`, it takes the same number of arguments (no varargs allowed) and all parameters have type `int`), the program will run as intended. However it's still very bad style to implicitly declare functions.

If it is defined with a different signature, you'll get undefined behaviour. This might lead to wrong results, memory corruption and/or crashes.